# How do I send values from both pins of the serial port?

Tags: shell-script, serial-port

I am trying to intercommunicate my linux system with my microcontroller.

I have configured DB-9 pins as full duplex RS485 as below:

[image: DB-9 RS-485]

I have connected Pin-7 with Pin-8.

I have connected Pin-2 with Pin-3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
stty cs8 cstopb parenb -parodd < /dev/ttyO0 #I configure the Serial Port here
while :
do
        echo -ne '\x00\x05\x00\x00\xFF\x00\x8D\xEB'>/dev/ttyO0
        usleep 10000
done
```

I can configure serial port using `stty` command.

It might be a silly thing to ask but I want the serial port to output the same value from both of the outlets(A and B of RS-485).

I want this because my microcontroller does not consider the signal as a Modbus-RTU signal.

But when I crosswire the pins the microcontroller considers it as a signal but does not accept it because it is not the correct signal.

I used another modbus master device to connect my microcontroller and the output from logic analyzer was like this:

[image: Logic Analyzer Output of other device]

But when my linux system connects to it, the output signal is like this:

[image: Logic Analyzer Output of Linux System]

How do I output the same signal from the both ends?

EDIT: I have connected the pins like in the picture below:

[image: Connections]

Then I have connected them to my microcontroller.

Comment: please draw a diagram of your connections ... it is unclear what is connected to what

Comment: @jsotola I drew and uploaded a sketch of the pins. Could you check that out?

Answer (score 0):

> I have configured DB-9 pins as full duplex RS485 as below

And do you also have hardware that works as RS485 with a differential signal, or do you have a normal serial port? Because normal serial port hardware doesn't produce RS485 signals, and your logic analyzer output very much looks like a normal serial port.

So you either need to buy RS485 hardware, you need to buy an RS232 to RS485 converter. Potentially you can make one yourself, that would be a question for the electronics stackexchange.

Comment: Why do you think the output signal looks like it is a normal serial port? I have followed the instructions to convert DB-9 to communicate as RS-485. How can I check if it is a normal serial port or not?

Comment: What were the instructions you followed? Link? If you mean "connect loopbacks A and B as in the image", then this isn't going to solve the problem, at all...

Comment: To be able to achieve differential signal of RS-485, what if I connect an inverter between my only signal pin and the other RS-485 pin of my microcontroller? But this seems wrong.